# Codeigniter adicionando ".html" após nome do controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess, php-5, codeigniter-2

Não sei por qual motivo quando tento realizar uma chamada ajax para a url "http://localhost/meusite/controller/metodo" recebo um erro 404 dizendo o seguinte "A url http://localhost/meusite/controller.html/metodo" não foi encontrada no servidor(404). Não consigo encontrar de onde vem esse ".html" que ele esta adicionando depois do nome do controller, a aplicação esta rodando perfeitamente em outro servidor.

Não sei de onde vem o problema mas vou postar o .htaccess pra ver se é algum erro nele:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

E esse é o trecho que faz a requisição:

```
var controller = 'login';
            var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';

            function validaLogin() {

                $.ajax({
                    'url' : base_url + controller + '/ax_validaLogin',
                    'type' : 'POST', //the way you want to send data to your URL
                    'data' : {'username': document.getElementById('username').value,
                              'senha'  : document.getElementById('senha').value
                             },
                    'success' : function(data){ //probably this request will return anything, it'll be put in var "data"
                        var container = $('#errorMessage'); //jquery selector (get element by id)

                        if(data == "sucesso") {
                            window.location.href='home';
                        }
                        else {
                            if(data){
                                container.html(data);
                                $("#erroLogin").show();
                                focusLogin();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Lembrando que estou usando Codeigniter 2, PHP5.6 e Apache2 num Linux Mint 18.

Comment: Talvez seja válido postar o trecho de código que faz a requisição AJAX.

Comment: Abra o arquivo `/application/config/config.php` e poste aqui. Talvez o item `url_suffix` não esteja nulo.

Comment: editei colocando a requisição, e verifiquei o arquivo config.php, url_suffix está assim: `$config['url_suffix'] = '' `

Comment: Se vc não está usando rotas estáticas `base_url('controller/method')` já deveria ser suficiente para chamar o controlador e o método. Isso aqui: `base_url + controller + '/ax_validaLogin'` é um exagero de expressão. E se vc usa o mesmo código em outro servidor e isso não acontece, **tem algo errado com a configuração de reescrita do Apache**.

Comment: hum, vou verificar oque eu puder sobre essa questão da reescrita, e sobre o base_url+controller... é um codigo legado que não foi eu quem desenvolveu. Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: seria bom se você debugasse o codigo no firebug, creio eu que o problema seja no caminho absoluto para o método, tente usar a caminho relativo, e no final do método do seu controller usar a função exit ou die para matar aplicação, caso não resolva favor postar print do debug do firefox ou chrome.